# Unable to see div in Apple devices

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter-3

I have a `div` part in my HTML page (codeigniter) which is appearing everywhere except the Apple devices

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-end px-4">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 family_member_sec_lab" id="family_member_sec_lab"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="input-group mr-1 w-196"><input type="text" id="dp1601100098104" class="form-control datetimepicker454 hasDatepicker" placeholder="Select Date"> <span class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text text-secondary"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could be the problem here?